# sudo -i only allows one argument

Tags: 10.04, bash, sudo

Is this normal?

```
> sudo -u misc -i "ls"
note test tmp
> sudo -u misc -i "ls ~"
-bash: ls ~: command not found
> sudo -u misc -i "ls ~"
-bash: ls ~: command not found
> sudo -u misc -i "foo=bar"
[misc]
```

Anything that's got a space in it seems to be interpreted as a single command, which is unrecognised. Even weirder, setting any environment variable drops me into the other user's account. How can I run those commands as expected?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The command and arguments passed to `sudo` should not be surrounded in quotes, so you can try

```
sudo -u misc -i ls -l
```

but

```
sudo -u misc -i ls ~
```

should not list `misc`'s home directory content, but your home, because the `~` character is expanded *before* been passed to `sudo`. You could try to avoid this using

```
sudo -u misc -i ls '~'
```

but this again doesn't work, because `sudo` do not invoke a shell to execute its command, so `~` has no meaning out of a shell.

Finally, the solution could be

```
sudo -u misc -i bash -c 'ls ~'
```

Comment: I never realised how complicated it is to do something this simple with sudo :). But this works and also works nicely setting environment variables. Thanks.

Comment: Just revisited this and found some gotchas, workarounds explained in this thread. http://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/bug-bash/2011-02/msg00095.html.

sudo -u misc -i bash -c 'cd /tmp ; pwd' doesn't work for example. Need sudo -u misc -i bash '-c "cd /tmp"'.

But a better way is to pipe it into bash (http://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/bug-bash/2011-02/msg00095.html):
echo 'cd /tmp; pwd' | sudo -u misc -i bash

Comment: @mahemoff: in those two threads there seem to be no reference to `sudo`, and the command `sudo -u user -i bash -c 'cd tmp; pwd'` works perfectly here.

Comment: No, not sudo, but similar idea. (I was searching for bash pwd as i figured others had similar issues.) I just tried now on a standard 10.04 build and pwd didn't show /tmp, it showed the home directory.

Answer (score 0):

It works for me but without the quotations marks:

> sudo -u test -i ls -lah ~

Comment: It lists your home, not that of `test`user.